# How to prevent sialolithiasis (salivary gland stones) from re-occurring

Tags: prevention, saliva, calculi-stones

[Sialolithiasis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sialolithiasis) is a condition where stones (calculi) form in the salivary glands or ducts, blocking the saliva from coming out.

I recently had two stones surgically removed from the beginning of the duct as it exits the submandibular gland:

[image]

The left stone is approximately 9mm across.

This was not cheap surgery, so I want to take steps to prevent re-occurrence.

- What steps should I take?
- Should I get a regular check to see if any stones have formed? (Small stones < 4mm can be removed with an endoscope). If so, how often?
- Has there been any research on steps to prevent stone formation?